# Why is a binding to another ViewModel not opening the corresponding View?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am trying to set up a binding on a button that navigates to a new view model when the button is clicked.

Here is my ViewModel :

```
public class NotificationsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public NotificationsViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
        : base(navigation)
    {
    }

    public void GoToNextPage()
    {
        _navigation.Navigate<AboutMeViewModel>();
    }

    public MvxCommand GoToNextPageCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(async () => await _navigation.Navigate<AboutMeViewModel>()); }
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor for the BaseViewModel it inherits from (I don't think the rest of BaseViewModel is relevant, but let me know if it might be useful to see):

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel, IBaseViewModel
{
    protected readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigation;

    public BaseViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
    }
}
```

Here is the View where I create the binding to this ViewModel:

```
public partial class NotificationsView : BaseView<NotificationsViewModel>
{
    public NotificationsView() : base("NotificationsView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<NotificationsView, NotificationsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(NextPageButton.Tap()).For(tap => tap.Command).To(nameof(ViewModel.GoToNextPage));
        set.Bind(NextPageCommandButton).To(nameof(ViewModel.GoToNextPageCommand));
        set.Apply();
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}


[Register ("NotificationsView")]
partial class NotificationsView
{
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UIKit.UIButton NextPageButton { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (NextPageButton != null) {
            NextPageButton.Dispose ();
            NextPageButton = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the BaseView it inherits from:

```
public abstract class BaseView<T> : MvxViewController<T>, IBaseView
    where T : BaseViewModel
{
    private object _headerToken = null;
    private object _addTaskToken = null;
    private UIView _originalView = null;       

    public BaseView(string name, NSBundle bundle)
        : base(name, bundle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        if (ViewModel == null)
            return;

        _headerToken = ViewModel.WeakSubscribe(() => ViewModel.IsLogoVisible, OnHeaderEnabledChanged);
        _addTaskToken = ViewModel.WeakSubscribe(() => ViewModel.IsAddTaskVisible, OnAddTaskEnabledChanged);

        ViewModel.Start();
    }
}
```

When I debug this code in the emulator, I can set a breakpoint inside of the the `GoToNextPage` that gets hit so I know the binding is catching the click event.  However, when I continue execution the navigation to the new view model does not happen but no exception is thrown.

I am able to navigate to this view model without a problem from another page, so I think something must be wrong with how I set up this binding.  As far as I can tell this binding is set up exactly the same as the one I have that is working. What am I missing here?

Comment: can you post the BaseView definition please?

Comment: Yup, BaseView definition and other partial class for NotificationsView have been added

Comment: You need to bind to a `Command`. More specific a `IMvxAsyncCommand`. Since you don't use an async Task to navigate your exceptions will be swallowed.

Comment: @Martijn00 Please see the updates I made.  I added another button to the view that binds to an MvxCommand, but am seeing the same behavior on that button.  Am I binding to that MvxCommand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an attribute for registering the view and one for mapping the view to the view model?

```
[Register("NotificationsView")] // this is missing...
[MvxViewFor(typeof(NotificationsViewModel))] // this is missing...
public partial class NotificationsView : BaseView<NotificationsViewModel>
{
    public NotificationsView() : base("NotificationsView", null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The attribute for registering the view is on the partial class in the NotificationsView.designer.cs file that is generated as part of the view.  I searched my project for the `MvxViewFor` attribute mapping the view to the view model and can't find it anywhere, so I don't think that's the difference in my case.  I will try it out though and let you know what I find.

Comment: Confirmed, adding the `MvxViewFor` attribute didn't change the behavior for me.  Based on [this post](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/195), it looks to me like there are multiple ways to bind views to view models in MvvmCross.